# I am getting following error with alamofire while posting as dictionary parameter

Tags: swift, alamofire

Request failed with error:

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

following is my code prior to my question

```
let requestURL: String = String(format: "%@", postURL)
    if let theJSONData = try?  JSONSerialization.data(
        withJSONObject: postDict,
        options: .prettyPrinted
        ),

        let JSonDATA = String(data: theJSONData, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {

        Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: JSonDATA as?  [String: AnyObject], encoding: JSONEncoding.default,  headers: [:])
            .responseJSON { response in switch response.result {

            case .success(let JSON):

                print("response :-----> ",response)

            case .failure(let error):

                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can someone help me out at earliest ?

Comment: Your help would be appreciated

Comment: `responseSerializationFailed`. "RESPONSE". That's the important part. Could you print `if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string}`? Also I don't understand why you are doing all this for the params, just, there seems to be so much wrong things about that: ` let JSonDATA = String()` followed by `JSonDATA as?  [String: AnyObject]` Why should `JSonDATA` be a Dictionary object? Why using `.prettyPrinted`? You should get a cast error in console. just do `method: .post, parameters: postDict`.

Comment: I have to pass a dictionary i.e. postDict as parameter using alamofire